# When total coins will exceed beyond its storage data type

Tags: stellar-core, transactions, inflation

The total initial coins are 1000000000000000000 which is stored in const int64_t data type. Now this particular data type can support maximum 19 digits number. 
THis whole coin is possessed by root account.

During inflation, as more coins will introduce in the system then lets assume that the destination of inflation is also the root account. 
Then how that account can hold number greater than that? will it not throw any error?

Answer (score 1):

It can not hold a higher number and will most likely result in some kind of a badass exception: halt+error in best case or wrong overflown numbers without notice in the worst case.

However if you consider that [all the money in the world](http://money.visualcapitalist.com/worlds-money-markets-one-visualization-2017/) can be described in a range up to 10 quadrillion USD (1e+16) then 1e+19 sounds like a perfectly reasonable maximum value for this data type.